# What is $\lim_{x \to 1} \sin(\frac{1}{x-1}) ?$

Tags: real-analysis

What is $\lim_{x \to 1} \sin(\frac{1}{x-1}) ?$

I have attempted this question by substituting 1 into the equation however I know I am not allowed to divide by zero, how would I attain a limit (I have not learnt any rules such as l'hopital's rule.

Thank you

Comment: This limit does not exist.

Comment: Just because you can write $\lim a_x$ doesn't mean the limit exists.  Don't ask "what is x".  Ask "Does x exist and if so what is it" and accept that the answer may be "No, x does not exist".

Comment: You can't divide by 0 and limits are to avoid dividing by zero to consider values as you approach the "divide by zero" singularity.   Basically (very informal) 1/(x - 1) -> $\infty$ as x -> 1.  So what is the limit of sin z as z goes to infinity.  Well, sin keeps circling for 1 to -1 to 1 and never approaches any single value.  So limit of sin z doesn't exist.  So neither does limit of sin 1/(x-1) as x -> 1.

Answer (score 3):

What is $\lim_{x \to 1} \sin(\frac{1}{x-1}) ?$

Define two sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{2n\pi}+1$ and $b_n =\frac{1}{2n\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$ + 1

$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n = 1$

$f(a_n) = 0$

$f(b_n)=1$

Therefore the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=\text{undefined in the interval} (-1,1)\text{limit does not exsist}$$

[image]